# Can you send sms without using the native ios application?

Tags: ios, xcode, sms, messenger

I have seen several tutorials to send SMS messages but all open the native iOS message application and what I want is that my application send it without changing application that is sending something invisible to the user.

This is the code I'm using but opens the native application:

```
    #pragma mark - IBAction methods
-(IBAction)sendSMS:(id)sender {
    //check if the device can send text messages
    if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Advertencia" message:@"Su dispositivo no permite el envio de mensajes SMS" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    //set receipients - telefonos
    NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textNumero.text, nil];
    NSLog(@"telefono: %@",recipients);
    //set message text
    NSString * message = textMensaje.text;
    NSLog(@"mensaje: %@",recipients);
    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [messageController setRecipients:recipients];
    [messageController setBody:message];

    // Present message view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate methods
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            break;

        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        {
            UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Advertencia" message:@"Ha ocurrido un error en el envio del mensaje" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [warningAlert show];
            break;
        }

        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: so basically bypass any ios security resrictions preventing apps from sending premium sms behind the user's back?

Comment: you say that restriction of apple whenever you want to send SMS must be from the native application, my idea is that the user in my application has a list of numbers and pressing a button to send a SMS predefined to that list straight from my app